# Is the counter in datasift.com page a real counter?

Tags: jquery, counter

I am looking at the counter at the page bottom of http://datasift.com/, after looking at the page source, I found that the counter is generated by JS code like below (store in this [link](http://datasift.com/sites/default/files/js/js_idtH4v08cW6QPrmvF5F9E72D54mv-QIRd4WGwPfjjrg.js)):

```
function UpdateClockCounter(count) {
  numberitems = jQuery('#clock ul').children('li').children('.number');
  number = '';
  numberitems.each(function(index, el) {
    number += jQuery(el).text();
  });
  number = number * 1 + count * 1;
  number = number.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
  revnumberitems = jQuery(numberitems.get().reverse());
  revnumberitems.each(function(index, el) {
    if( i = number.charAt(index))
      jQuery(el).text(i);
    else
      jQuery(el).text('0');
  });
}
```

There is no communication with server side when the counter is refreshed. Can I say this counter is a fake counter? Or do I miss anything here?

I am asking this question because I want to implement something similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's completely fake. Not even the start value is real. Great way to build confidence in their service. Here's how that function is called:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      var start = Math.round(
          new Date("April 01, 2011 00:00:00").getTime()/1000);
      var time = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
      var d = time - start;
      var count = 1000000 + (d * 3000);

      SetClockCounter(count);

      setInterval(function() {
         var number = 
              Math.floor((Math.random() * (2500 - 3000 + 1) + 2500)/10);
         UpdateClockCounter(number);
      }, 100);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is based on the number of tweets through the twitter firehose. We process thousands of tweets, facebook posts, blogs and other data every second. You can feel free to see the rate data goes through our service: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/11/29/datasift-architecture-realtime-datamining-at-120000-tweets-p.html

So yes, it is fake as you spotted from the JS, but based on the rough average throughput of our filtering and streaming servers. It's more efficient to use these figure rather than spend time creating a service that will count and sit there are as a REST service returning JSONP responses. You'd find the real figures aren't too dissimilar. We are talking billions and billions of "interactions" so being out by a few thousand is only 1 seconds worth of data going through the platform.

Comment: Hi Ollie, thank you for your reply. I also guess the counter data is based on some average rate instead of using total fake data. However the counter gives user impression of high precision of the counter data, while in fact it is an estimation.